# Como carregar uma URL que esta dentro de um .txt pelo Web View?

Tags: java, android

É o seguinte, eu estou fazendo um aplicativo que é uma espécie de webBrowser. Nesse aplicativo, eu tenho uma url escrita dentro de um .txt, e eu preciso carregar essa URL dentro do meu WebView. Segue o que eu já fiz:

*OBS: Eu já consigo carregar uma URL no meu WebView especificando-a no próprio código do apk como vocês podem ver nos códigos abaixo.*

***activity_main.xml:***

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="@drawable/engrenagem"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_margin="20px" />
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.abacoti.awser;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;  ;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String webURL = "http://www.google.com.br/";
    WebView web;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            web.loadUrl(webURL);
        }
        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState )
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        web.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        web.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Não está muito claro o que você quer fazer. Pode exemplificar melhor?

Comment: Você quer carregar uma página a partir de um URL especificado num arquivo de texto ou queres renderizar o que está no arquivo de texto dentro do `WebView`?

Comment: A URL (LINK) está escrita dentro do arquivo TXT?

Comment: Exatamente! Vou editar a pergunta!

Comment: Vou re-abrir a pergunta, mas na próxima evita mudar tanto a pergunta com edições, especialmente quando já houver respostas. Até breve!

Comment: Obrigado! De qualquer jeito, o Guilherme já tinha respondido e editou a resposta dele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a URL esta dentro de um TXT você precisará ler este TXT primeiro usando, claro que o arquivo deve conter apenas a URL.

Usando como base esta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/12421888/1518921 você deverá fazer isto (se o arquivo for no SD):

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Pega o arquivo de text
File file = new File(sdcard, "MEU_ARQUIVO_TXT_COM_A_URL.txt");

//Pra obter a string
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Erro de leitura do arquivo");
}

web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
web.loadUrl(text.toString());
```

Se estiver na pasta assets do aplicativo:

```
//Equivale ao android_asset/MEU_ARQUIVO_TXT_COM_A_URL.txt
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("MEU_ARQUIVO_TXT_COM_A_URL.txt");

//Pra obter a string
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF8");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Erro de leitura do arquivo");
}

web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
web.loadUrl(text.toString());
```

> O AP mudou o sentido da pergunta, por isto risquei a resposta anterior, pra qualquer problema semelhante recomendo tentar esta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/133955/3635

<s>Se o arquivo estiver na pasta assets você tem que carrega-lo assim:</s>

```
WebView view = new WebView(this);
view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/foo.txt");
setContentView(view);
```

Se quiser acessar outros arquivos é necessário usar:

- Retorna o caminho do primeiro cartão (ou outro tipo de armazenamento externo):

  ```
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
  ```
- Retorna o caminho do sistema (como o Android é um linux você provavelmente terá algo como `/` e não poderá gravar na maioria das pastas):

  ```
   Environment.getRootDirectory().toString();
  ```

Então o caminho deve ficar algo como:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/pasta/foo.txt";

WebView view = new WebView(this);
view.loadUrl(path);
setContentView(view);
```

Segue documentação:

- http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/projects/index.html
- http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Comment: Na verdade, é um arquivo (.txt) localizado na raiz do dispositivo.

Comment: fica uma tela branca

Comment: Certo, estou aqui...

Comment: Coloquei recompensa ok?

Comment: Já que vou usar o próprio "HD" do dispositivo, seria System.out.print(Environment.getRootDirectory().toString());?

Comment: Guilherme continua a tela branca...

Comment: Você está falando do logcat? Se sim, não consigo achar nada relacionado a essa linha.

Comment: Nada ainda, olha o jeito que eu estou colocando:

`web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        System.out.print("meu log:" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/awser/url.txt";
        WebView view = new WebView(this);
        view.loadUrl(path);
        setContentView(view);`

Comment: Como eu te mando todo o log por aqui? É bem grande!

Comment: Aqui! http://pastebin.com/jY6PT40Z

Comment: Certo! Até amanhã te dou resposta!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40854/discussion-between-marcos-sartorato-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: Muito Obrigado!