# Como abrir arquivos .html no meu aplicativo?

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo um aplicação para Android e queria saber como faço para abrir e exibir um arquivo `.html` especifico localizado no cartão SD diretamente no meu aplicativo.

Comment: Quero somente visualizar o .html offline dentro do APP mesmo

Comment: Por exemplo, existe um arquivo chamado "arquivo.html" no cartão SD, quero visualiza-lo em forma de página da web

Comment: Um especifico que esteja no cartão SD

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta Drkill32 conforme teus comentários, se discordar de algo edite novamente e explique o que realmente deseja, eu postei uma resposta, tente ela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vai depender muito de onde o arquivo se encontra, sendo um local especifico, primeiro adicione um `webView` ao teu app, no caso aqui o nome ficou `webView1`, se usar outro ID para o teu webView deverá trocar nos exemplos abaixo o `webView1` pelo ID que estiver usando.

Depois vai precisar da classe [Environment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html):

- [Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#MEDIA_MOUNTED) verificar se tem cartão SD
- [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) obtém o caminho do cartão

O código deve ficar algo como:

```
WebView meuWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
    Log.d("Teste html no SD", "sem cartão SD");
} else {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //Esta linha é apenas para teste
    Log.d("Teste html no SD", "file://" + path + "/pasta/arquivo.html");

    meuWebView.loadUrl("file://" + path + "/pasta/arquivo.html");
}
```

Não tenho o [ADT](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) instalado então não pude testar, mas se o exemplo acima não funcionar e o caminho `"file://" + path + "/pasta/arquivo.html"` estiver errado (conforme o `Log.d`), então tente isto:

```
WebView meuWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
    Log.d("Teste html no SD", "sem cartão SD");
} else {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    //Esta linha é apenas para teste
    Log.d("Teste html no SD", "file://" + path + "/pasta/arquivo.html");

    meuWebView.loadUrl("file://" + path + "/pasta/arquivo.html");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!!